# how to print lines in a file by seeking a position from another text file in python?

Tags: python, file

This is my code for getting lines from a file by seeking a position using f.seek() method but I am getting a wrong output. it is printing  from middle of the first line.
can u help me to solve this please?

```
f=open(r"sample_text_file","r")
last_pos=int(f.read())
f1=open(r"C:\Users\ddadi\Documents\project2\check\log_file3.log","r")
f1.seek(last_pos)
for i in f1:
    print i
    last_position=f1.tell()
    with open('sample_text.txt', 'a') as handle:
        handle.write(str(last_position))
```

sample_text file contains the file pointer offset  which is returned by f1.tell()

Comment: How did you get the magic figure `419490`?

Comment: Please provide sample input, what the current output is and the expected output. Otherwise people, including me, will have a very difficult time helping you out.

Comment: ok sure  actually I am getting that value by using f.tell() method and i just stored in a text file from that text file I am reading that value @Nehal J Wani

Comment: ok  I will update my code @jockster

Comment: I have updated my code can you please check it once. @jockster

Answer (score 1):

If it's printing from the middle of a line that's almost certainly because your offset is wrong. You don't explain how you came by the magic number you use as an argument to `seek`, and without that information it's difficult to help more precisely.

One thing is, however, rather important. It's not a very good idea to use `seek` on a file that is open in text mode (the default in Python). Try using `open(..., 'rb')` and see if the process becomes a little more predictable. It sounds as though you may have got the offset by counting characters after reading in text mode, but good old Windows includes carriage return characters in text files, which are removed by the Python I/O routines before your program sees the text.

Comment: Thank u so much for responding @holdenweb. I will try this

Comment: but we are working in python 2.7 and  also f.seek() method is not accepting binary value